# How to just more a string of more than 1 character in a regex replace expression vb.net

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net

Right I'm to remove some quotes from a xml file I've downloaded from Wikipedia. So far The text looks like this (ignore the line breaks, that's just so it's easier to read):

```
'''Anarchism''' is a political philosophy that advocates stateless societies based on 
non-hierarchical free associations.<ref name="iaf-ifa.org"/><ref>"That is why 
Anarchy, when it works to destroy authority in all its aspects, when it demands
 the abrogation of laws and the abolition of the mechanism that serves to
 impose them, when it refuses all hierarchical organization and preaches free agreement - at the same time strives to maintain and enlarge the precious kernel of social customs without which
 no human or animal society can exist." Peter Kropotkin. http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/Petr_Kropotkin__Anarchism__its_philosophy_and_ideal.html
 Anarchism: its philosophy and ideal</ref><ref>"anarchists are opposed to irrational (e.g., illegitimate) 
authority, in other words, hierarchy - hierarchy being the institutionalisation of authority 
within a society." http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/The_Anarchist_FAQ_Editorial_Collective__An_Anarchist_FAQ__03_17_.html#toc2 "B.1 
Why are anarchists against authority and hierarchy?" in An 
Anarchist FAQ</ref><ref>"ANARCHISM, a social philosophy that rejects
 authoritarian government and maintains that voluntary institutions are best
 suited to express man's natural social tendencies." George Woodcock. "Anarchism" at The Encyclopedia of Philosophy</ref><ref>"In a society developed on these lines, the voluntary 
associations which already now begin to cover all the fields of human activity
 would take a still greater extension so as to substitute themselves for the 
state in all its functions." http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/Petr_Kropotkin___Anarchism__from_the_Encyclopaedia_Britannica.html
 Peter Kropotkin. "Anarchism" from the Encyclopædia Britannica</ref> Anarchism holds the state
 to be undesirable, unnecessary, or harmful
```

All I want from this block of text is this:

> Anarchism is a political philosophy that advocates stateless societies based on non-hierarchical free associations. Anarchism holds the state to be undesirable, unnecessary, or harmful.

It seem to me that if I remove all text between `"<ref"` and `"/ref>"` I should be able to capture all the required undesirable text and remove it. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
        Dim temptext As String = newsrt.ToString
        Dim expression As New Regex("(?<=\<ref)[^/ref>]+(?=/ref>)")
        Dim resul As String = expression.Replace(temptext, "")
```

But this doesn't seem to work. No text between the `<ref` and `/ref>` is captured and replaced with "".

Any help or advice would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how negated character classes work. The class disallows any single of the characters `/`, `r`, `e`, `f`, `>`. Also, you don't even want to rule out `/ref>` at all, because you want to remove all the intermediate `ref`s as well. You can simply use `.*`. Also, you don't want lookarounds, because these exclude the things matched inside them from the match. But you *do* want to remove those tags as well. Hence, in your case, it should be as simple as:

```
"<ref.*/ref>"
```

Since `*` is greedy, this match will simply go from the first `<ref` to the last `/ref>` - usually a big problem of greediness, but in your particular case exactly what's desired.

You might want to use `RegexOptions.Singleline` so that `.` matches line breaks, if there are any.

Comment: Hey. I'm pretty new to regex but I think I understand what greedy is-> it'll find the last location of the end section (/ref>)? If so how to I stop this since there's the potentail for there to be lots these references up and down the pages, with the wanted text in between.

Comment: I got it, add a ? like so: "<ref.*?/ref>". Thanks for you help! :D

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg in that case, you can either make it ungreedy like `<ref.*?/ref>` or use `<ref(?:(?!/ref>).)*/ref>` (which is what you originally intended). Or, much better, use an XML parser!